# Python: debugging and auto reload on docker container

Tags: python, docker, debugging, celery, watchdog

Mi situation is: I'm developing some docker containers. One of these containers is a celery app that get some tasks from another app and process these tasks.

As I'm working everything in the containers I need to debug on the container and also I need some reloading of the app when the code changes.

I can make both things to work separately using **debugpy** for debugging and **watchmedo** for reloading. My problem comes when trying to combine both of them: debugging + reloading in celery.

EXTRA INFO:
I've already a Flask app container where I can achieve this by only using **debugpy**. I don't need **watchmedo** nor **inotify** because flask already come with the *--reload* option. NICE! But this doesn't happen with celery since its old *--autoreload* option has been removed some time ago.

**DEBUGGING:**

To achieve the debugging I've made the following in my dockerfile:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "debugpy",  "--wait-for-client",  "--listen", "0.0.0.0:9999", "-m", "celery", "-A", "celery_main", "worker", "-l", "INFO", "-n", "worker", "--concurrency=1"]
```

That works fine but there is not reload on code changes.

**RELOADING:**

To achieve reloading I've made the following in my dockerfile.

```
CMD ["watchmedo" "shell-command" "--patterns" "'*.py'" "--recursive" "--command='celery -A celery_main worker -l INFO -n worker --concurrency=1'"]
```

That is also fine for reloading but I miss the debugging.

**ATTEMPT: MIX**

So I tried mixing both things but it doesn't seem to work. I just get nothing:

```
CMD ["watchmedo" "shell-command" "--patterns" "'*.py'" "--recursive" "--command='python -m debugpy  --wait-for-client  --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 -m celery -A celery_main worker -l INFO -n worker --concurrency=1'"]
```

BTW a problem that I guess will come if this eventually works, is that every time the code changes, the whole debugpy... command will be executed and that means that I must re-run the debugger on my IDE which is VSCODE.

Any idea how to solve this issue(s) ??

Comment: Hey, usually when debugging you do not really want the code to change, right? If the different docker commands are a hassle you could, for example, create separate images/layers, or write a script as the entrypoint of the container so you can easily pass a command `reload` or `debug`.

Comment: Hi Deproblemify . You might want to change your code, of course. If not: what's the point of finding a bug?. Would you stop, change and re run when you could just change it and reload automatically? I finally got a solution to this problem and it is working very well. There are some edge cases where you need to reload the container manually but it works.

Comment: If you found a solution, do you mind sharing it with everyone as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the CMD below:

CMD python -m debugpy --wait-for-client --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 -m watchdog.watchmedo auto-restart -d src_dir/ -p '*.py' --recursive -- celery -A celery_main worker -l info

Answer (score 0):

I could not make watchmedo + debugpy work for celery workers. However, if you are using Django, [here](https://blog.derlin.ch/auto-reload-plus-debug-django-and-django-celery-workers#heading-debugging-a-django-celery-worker-running-in-docker-with-auto-reload) is described something that works.

Basically, create a file `worker.py` with the following content:

```py
import django
# ❗ needs to be called *before* importing autoreload
django.setup()

from django.utils import autoreload

def run_celery():
    # ↓ import the Celery app object from your code
    from my_package.celery.app import app as celery_app
    # ↓ usual celery arguments
    args = "-A my.package.worker worker -l info -P solo --queues a,b"

    celery_app.worker_main(args.split(" "))

print("Starting celery worker with autoreload...")
autoreload.run_with_reloader(run_celery)
```

Once you have that, use this command:

```bash
sh -c "pip install debugpy && python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:3000 worker.py"
```

The original article has more info, check out [How to auto reload & debug Django and Django Celery workers running in Docker (VS Code)](https://blog.derlin.ch/auto-reload-plus-debug-django-and-django-celery-workers)